# How to make sure static variable changes of one singleton scoped class is visible to another prototyped scoped class?

Tags: spring-boot

I have a class A in spring boot with prototype scope.
I have two objects of class A. Each object runs a method in a infinite loop in two different threads that accesses static variable of class B.
The static variable of class B is updated by some API call.
But the static variable changes are not visible to the prototype object.
Give me a solution to make sure that the changes in static variable of class B object are visible to A?

Answer (score 0):

Static class member is by definition one per class and not per instance. You also don't need to have an instance of the class to access the static variable. So assume you have on class B

```
public class B {
  private static Integer myStaticNumber;
...
  public static Integer getMyStaticNumber() {
    return myStaticNumber;
  }

  public static void setMyStaticNumber(Integer num) {
    myStaticNumber = num;
  }
...
}
```

So, anywhere in the code you can do

```
B.getMyStaticNumber();
```

And get the current value.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you are trying to do something like this:

```java
class A {
    //done in an infinite loop by two threads
    void read() {
        String readValue = B.theVariable;
        //soma additional logic
    }
}

class B {
    static String theVariable;
}

class ApiController {
    void call(String arg) {
        B.theVariable = arg;
    }
}
```

I intentionally didn't put any Spring Boot annotations, because, If I understand you correctly, this is not an issue of a Spring Boot, but rather problem with multithreading.

In java, you cannot modify a variable in one thread and expect the change to be visible in another thread if you didn't do any synchronization. I don't know how you are modyfing this variable, so it is hard to advice any concrete fix. Here are some examples, depending on what is `theVariable` and how is it modified.

## The Variable is always replaced by the new value

If the variable is always replaced and its value does not depend of its previous state, then simply adding `volatile` keyword would be enough.

Here is an example:

```java
class B {
    static volatile String theVariable;
}

class ApiController {
    void call(String arg) {
        B.theVariable = arg; //always replacing the variable
    }
}
```

## The variable is an integer and its value depends on its previous state

If the variable happens to be an integer and is stateful (so the final value depends of its previous value) then, for example, using `AtomicInteger` would do the trick:

```java
class B {
    static AtomicInteger theVariable;
}

class ApiController {
    void call(int arg) {
        B.theVariable.addAndGet(arg); //sample operation on atomic integer
    }
}
```

## The variable is some other object and its value depends on its previous state

It that case some explicit synchronization would be needed. It is impossible to answer how to do it if I don't know your usecase. Some simple synchronization may look like this:

```java
class B {
    private static String theVariable;

    static synchronized void modifyTheVariable(String foo) {
        theVariable = theVariable + foo; //sample operation on variable
    }
}

class ApiController {
    void call(String arg) {
        B.modifyTheVariable(arg);
    }
}
```

## Some final thoughts

I know that it is not related to your question, but I think you should rethink the architecture of your solution. Having a singleton with a static field that is modified and read by other classes sounds like code smell (probably the [Global Data](https://luzkan.github.io/smells/global-data)).